# Rails show posts with most recent comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using relations, my posts have many comments.

How do I show the posts that have the most recent comments? Or, more importantly, how do I show posts with most recent comments of a particular type? Each comment has a "comment_type" field, so I want to find all posts that are most recently commented on with a particular comment type.  This should be a simple scope, but can't figure it out.

This is what I have currently, but this is still returning all posts, not filtering out posts that don't have a recent comment of the type `com_date_due`.

`@posts = Post.includes(:comments).upcoming`

```
  scope :upcoming, -> {
    order('comments.created_at ASC')
    .where('comments' => {com_type: 'com_date_due', com_date: Time.now-1.day..Time.now+1.week})
  }
```

UPDATE:

Here's a timeline flow of how I want to grab the parent item: I query by each "comment", by my current method, it will still return the tool, even the most relevant "due date" is the topmost one and shouldn't be within the date query.  How can I grab items based on the associated records in this timeline? I need to only query the first item in related associated records.[image]

Comment: add an `includes` to `comments`

Comment: Sorry, that object already includes comments. Let me update.

Comment: add that in the scope

Comment: @SunnyK, no change.  What I want to do is order children of a particular type by `com_date`, then select ONLY THE FIRST COMMENT, then select parents that have a `child.com_date` within that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I show posts with most recent comments of a particular type

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :upcoming_comments, ->(type='com_date_due') { includes(:comments).where(comments: {comment_type: type, created_at: Time.now-1.day..Time.now+1.week}).order(comments: {created_at: :asc}) }
end
```

Your question is quite broad, so this is what I'd expect to use: `@posts = Post.upcoming_comments`. If you have more specific requirements, you'd be best amending your original question with them.

Comment: Thanks, Rich. This still includes posts with comments that are irrelevant. I'm having trouble explaining...NDA's suck. I want to get all `Items` with an associated record's `due_date` that is most recent. So if an Item has 3 "due dates", most recent is +1year (one is due this week), but it's querying this week's due dates, it will pick the Item because it has an associated due date within this week, even though there's a more accurate future due date. Make sense? Please chat if it's better.

Comment: Ya, I want to grab the Post with the latest comment with `type` "due_date" that has a `item_date` within that time range.  Again, because I'm having trouble being clear, my current queries grab all comments that are within that date range...I don't know how to limit or exclude the previous due dates. Follow?